# Python : detect dominant wavelength of a signal

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I have this signal, for which I want to calculate the dominant wavelength, which would be the distance between the pronounced minima where the oscillations occure:[image]
Which tool in scipy should I look into for this mission?

Answer (score 1):

It depends where you get the data from.

If you only have the (x,y) points of the graph, you can either hack it by taking all the `x` corresponding to the minimal `y` (be careful of floating-point equalities, though), or use the Fourier transform, identify the main wave (the biggest amplitude) and deduce its wavelength. For the latter, you would use the Fast Fourier Transform from scipy: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/tutorial/fftpack.html#fast-fourier-transforms

If you have the functional description of the function, either sample it like you do to construct the graph and apply the above, or take its derivative to find the minima mathematically (best method). You could also use scipy to find the minima numerically (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html), but you have to manually specify intervals that contain only one local minimum.